# В Xml файле найти всех потомков, имеющих потомков, с помощью xpath и Nokogiri

Tags: xml, ruby, nokogiri

Есть Exml файл, спарсил его, потом из него достал всех потомков относительно главного родителя и все это положил в массив. Но проблема в том, что нужно достать не всех потомков, а тех, которые имеют своих потомков. Собственно вопрос, как это реализовать? Есть идея взять всех этих потомков(которые уже в массиве) и перепроверить уже их на наличие потомков, и которые будут тру, записывать в массив. Но еще проблема в том, что не пойму чем именно являются те элементы, которые я уже записал в массив (все потомки), объектом или чем-то еще, будут ли они каждый по отдельности знать кем они были в файле, как-то так, буду благодарен за разъяснения.

Answer (score 0):

> XML

```
<root>
    <row id="1">
        <city>Miami</city>
    </row>
    <row id="2">
        <city/>
    </row>
    <row id="3">
        <city>Hollywood</city>
    </row>
    <row id="4">
    </row>
</root>
```

> XPath #1

```
/root/row[child::*]
```

ответ: `<row>` with id = (1,2,3)

> Xpath #2

```
/root/row/city[text()]
```

ответ: `<city>` with (Miami,Hollywood)

> XPath #3

```
/root/row/city[string-length(text()) eq 0]
```

ответ: `<city/>`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но тут понятно, файл маленький, и вложенность тоже маленькая, мой файл очень большой, дерево ветвления тоже глубокое, плюс я не знаю все узлы, если бы знал то мог бы к ним по ид обратится.

Comment: Те же принципы применимы к вашему XML. Первое выражение XPath ищет <row> с дочерними элементами на любом уровне.